# What time is GOOGLECLOCK() in Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula, google-apps

Hello What time is GOOGLECLOCK() in Spreadsheets?

I know, from the documentation, that GoogleClock "Returns the current date and time according to your computer system" (quote).

But what about when the spreadsheet is opened client side by a time-driven trigger? What time will GoogleClock() be?

If anyone has any ideas, please kindly share. 
Many thanks for looking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GOOGLECLOCK function was deprecated several years ago. It's no longer included in the official [Google Sheets functions lists](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and easy to test. This will illustrate that the documentation is confusing, and likely wrong. *(But it's on the Internet, so it must be true!)*

1. Set the formula in cell A1 to `GoogleClock()`.
2. Enter test script. This just reads the value in A1, and writes it to A2.
3. Set a time based trigger to fire once, at a known time.
4. Close your spreadsheet, leaving only the trigger to use it.
5. Go back to your spreadsheet after the trigger has run, and check the results.

After it fires, you'll see that A2 = A1, at least until A1 changes as it does each minute. I think that the documentation might mean that the time will be displayed according to the timezone and locale of your computer; but it isn't reading the time from your computer. So the actual source of the clock is the same as it is for the `Today()` function; the server it's executing on.

```
function testGoogleClock () {
  var curGClock = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2").setValue(curGClock);
}
```

As a further experiment, change the time on your PC; make it 10 minutes off, say. Look at your spreadsheet, and watch for `GoogleClock()` to tick. It keeps network time, regardless of what your PC is set to.

Next, change your PC's time zone. Check `GoogleClock()`. You'll find it doesn't match the time zone change... still keeps network time, regardless of what your PC is set to.

What about the spreadsheet settings? Change those to be in a different time zone, and you'll find that `GoogleClock()` matches it.

The docs should say..

> Returns the current date and time according to ***the*** computer system.

Or, to be consistent with the documentation for `Now()`...

> Returns the computer system time and date. Updates automatically each minute on the minute (unlike the NOW function).

PS: fix your time settings after these experiments!

Comment: Interesting (?) observation: With `GoogleClock()` in any cell of your spreadsheet, your whole spreadsheet is recalculated every minute on the minute. As a result, any `Now()` function will inherit the behaviour of `GoogleClock()`.

Comment: Great answer and method of investigation! Thanks for sharing that with us. It seems the spreadsheet settings also affects currency.